# How to copy an element in Photoshop without creating a new layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, copy-and-paste

I drew one star and in that particular layer I want to copy paste it. Is there any way to do so in photoshop?
I must keep all the stars in one layer but induvial so that I can edit them in animation. (I dnt want smart object)

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain who forces you to keep them in one layer? If you had them each in its own layer the layers could have descriptive names such as Mars, Jupiter, NGC 1234  Spiral Galaxy in Eridanus, etc... and every item could be accessed in the layers pane and in scripts.

Comment: No Scott, One tutorial forcing me  :'( . there that guy kept all the stars in one layer( He doesnt show or tell how :@ ) then in After Effects he applied some expression on that later to make all the stars glitter! I am dying to achieve same thing! But could not pull it  :'(

Comment: I attached that guy's layer. See how did he do that? :'( :'( :'(

Comment: Oh Sorry! wrong naming, face palm.

Comment: A layer group can get very much the same treatments as a single layer. But the "guy" seems to be in a video editor, not in a Photoshop in an ordinary graphics design mode.

Comment: he converted photoshop and ai file in shape layer. but in both case his stars were in one layer only. Okay am trying yours way and Scott's way too..  :'(

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your title to actually be a concise question and added a few tags. If this twists your post beyond your intended meaning, feel free to roll back my edits!

Comment: @Vincent No worries. It's okay.

Comment: Bit late, but: good to have you back :)

Comment: Lol. Wish I can like it like fb @Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Photoshop, duplicating layers is essentially the same as copy/paste.

I'd use the shortcut... so...

- <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to duplicate the layer...

- then move it...

If you then want all the copies on the same layer, highlight the layers in the **Layers Panel** and `Merge` them via <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

---

You can do the above in essentially **one step** though when working with pixel layers. And that can sometimes be better than copy/pasting or duplicating layers.

- Create a **selection** around your single star.
- Grab the **Move Tool**
- Hold the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key down
- Drag the star you have.

The selection will be duplicated (on the same layer) as you move it

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.